# Need VB code to display a list of worksheets in an Excel file, display them in a listbox on an Access form

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am building a form in Access that will allow a user to select an excel file, and then select a worksheet to import.  I have code that allows a user to select an Excel file and it stores the filename in a control on the form.

Now I want to display the names of the worksheets that are in that file.  I know how to do the import, what I don't know is how to get the worksheet names in the file and store them either in a table, or a listbox on the form so the user can select one.  Sadly, although all the Excel files are supposed to have standard names for the worksheets, some of the sheets are off and that is why I want to display them.

I am using Office 2007.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set oWkb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
For Each oSh In oWkb.Worksheets
   MsgBox oSh.Name
Next
```

oXLApp would be an instance of the Excel application, which you can get using `Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Make sure you close your workbook when you are done getting the sheet names. I would probably store them in a collection or an array (instead of the `MsgBox oSh.Name`) so that you can collect them, close the workbook, and display them on your form using the contents of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, using an ADOX Catalog to retrieve the worksheet names appears significantly faster than opening an Excel application instance to enumerate the `WorkSheets` collection.

```vb
Public Sub List_WorksheetsAdox(ByVal pWorkBook As String)
    Dim cat As Object 'ADOX.Catalog
    Dim cn As Object 'ADO.Connection
    Dim strConnect As String
    Dim tbl As Object 'ADOX.Table
     
    strConnect = "Provider=" & _
        CurrentProject.Connection.Provider & ";" & _
        "Data Source='" & pWorkBook & "';" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
     
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open strConnect
    Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = cn
     
    For Each tbl In cat.Tables
        Debug.Print tbl.Name
    Next tbl
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set cat = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This approach will include the dollar sign after each sheet name, which may not be what you want.  You could strip it off easily.

I tested using Excel 8.0 for my xls 2003 format workbook.  It appears the Excel 2007 format would require "Excel 12.0" for Extended Properties.  You can find more details at [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel).

As in the other answers, you will want to do something more useful with `tbl.Name` other than `Debug.Print` it.

Note this approach will list both named ranges and worksheets.  If that is an issue for you, you can distinguish between them based on whether or not the name includes a dollar sign ("$") on the end.  Sheets have the dollar sign; named ranges do not.

Comment: That code will also list named ranges, which can be useful. Named ranges do not have $ after the name. There is one more point floating in the murk, but it is not coming to the fore at the moment :(

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyBook.xls") ' Or whatever

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
    ' This prints the name in the Immediate window.
    ' You'll want to do something useful with them instead.
Next ws
```

To use this, must set reference to Excel object library: Tools > References > set checkmark next to Microsoft Excel xx.0 Object Library.